# Can I upload Flash (swf) to drupal 7?

Tags: files

http://drupal.org/project/flashnode
The module that I found only works for drupal 6.
Is there a module for drupal 7?

Also, there seems to be no tag label called Flash... Maybe an advance user would want to add that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google search for *add flash to drupal 7* gives the [SWF Embed](http://drupal.org/project/swfembed) module as the first result.

You could also look at the [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) suite of modules, which can give you a much more user friendly interface at the expense of some additional time invested in figuring out which of the modules you need.